# ufw blocks KVM guest from getting ip address and accessing network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, bridge, ufw

I need help getting ufw on a host computer to allow traffic to a virtual machine that it hosts.

More specifically, I am running Ubuntu 23.04 Server with a KVM virtual machine on a bridged network.  My router (192.168.1.1) assigns separate static ip addresses to the host (192.168.1.26) and guest (192.168.1.11) based on their mac addresses.  Everything works fine when ufw is disabled.  As soon as ufw is enabled, I cannot access the guest from the network.

What ufw rules do I need to use to allow the guest access to the network?  Here are some details of the various network interfaces.

The host's physical network interface is `enp1s0`
The bridge is `br0`
The guest's virtual network interface is `vnet0`
There also two bridges named `virbr0` and `docker0`

`brctl show` indicates that both `enp1s0` and `vnet0` are associated interfaces with bridge `br0`. The `virbr0` and `docker0` bridges do not have any interfaces associated with them.

Is there some ufw rule that I can use to allow network access to and from the guest?

I have read that I need to set up forwarding rules in /etc/ufw/before.rules as explain in the link below:

https://gist.github.com/plembo/38ae4e8b255fdd61ef592f7b05cd1e1a

This works as long as the host machine has an ip address to start with.  The problem is that the guest does not get an ip address when the host first boots up.  On boot up, ufw is enabled and this seems to prevent the guest from getting an ip address so the forwarding rules are in effective.  What is the solution?

I have seen others recommending that I turn off netfilter on the bridge.  Wouldn't this expose both host and guest to potential security issues?

Comment: what ufw rules are in place? Those settings you mention in the last paragraph simply disable packets traversing the bridge from being processed by iptables. So the host shouldn't be exposed, and as long as the guest has its own firewall, then there shouldn't be any exposure there either

Comment: My only ufw rules are the default ones (deny incoming, allow outgoing, and deny routed, plus allow 22/tcp and allow 123/udp.

The issue is I want to expose the guest so it can get an ip address from the dhcp server running on the router.

Comment: In my KVM hosts that need UFW, I *turn off netfilter on the bridge* - I just make sure the guests have an active firewall, then there is no issue

Comment: Does turning off netfilter on the bridge expose the host to any security risks?